# Google Map LatLng generator

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is someone know a online Google Map "LatLng" generator that can give  all "LatLng" when i click and save my multiple clicks "Latlng" that i can copy.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you please elobrate your question.?

Comment: I have to make very big map also need many Latlng to do that. I'm looking for a genarater who can give my all Latlng on my mouse click and i can copy all Latlng. My english is weak so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you are looking for, but when you mean that you are looking for a way to collect the LatLng's for clicks on a map you only have to observe the `click`-event of the map and store the `latLng`-property of the click-event somewhere(e.g. in a element in the page where you can select and copy it).

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/JM8H8/

Comment: Thank @Dr.Molle, you give me the thing what i was looking for. can you please help me to make a search bar on http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/JM8H8/.

Comment: what kind of "search bar"?

Comment: To search the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, the first answer which comes to my mind is : It is **impossible** to get **all** latitude / longitude of the world. It's like if you tried to get position of all points on the Earth, that makes no sens.

If you want to test your application with a lot of markers, just generates random coordinates (in a `for loop` for example), then, do what you want with these coordinates.